# 'extractApksForDebug' not found

Tags: android

An android app fails to build and run and displays this error message.

```
Task 'extractApksForDebug' not found in project ':app'.
```

When I tried to clean and build again, this error comes

```
Task 'bundleDebug' is ambiguous in project ':app'. Candidates are: 'bundleDebugAndroidTestResources', 'bundleDebugResources'.
```

How can I find the error and correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Help > Check for Updates.

Update all.

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

On right pane of android studio click on Gradle > Right click on project > Refresh Gradle dependencies.